# jQuery : selector question (stylesheet class)

Tags: jquery, selector

how can i select items with a classname that contains spaces?
like `<a href='button normal'>`

thx

Comment: Keep in mind that a class name with spaces is really considered, for CSS purposes, to be two classes.

Answer (score 3):

*I'm assuming your example meant `class=""` rather than `href=""` here.*

You can select them using the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (class is just another attribute in this case).  The use looks like this (change or remove the `a` part if needed):

```
$("a[class*=' ']")
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 has various [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), which work in jQuery. Most of them don't treat spaces in any special way; `$('a[class="button normal"]')` will select the link whose class attribute is exactly `button normal`. Or if you want to select elements which have `button` and `normal` classes (and possibly several more), use `$('.button.normal')`. (This is also plain old CSS, but does not work in IE6 due to a bug - the jQuery version does.)